# Get fully qualified resource name in web application in Java

Tags: java, spring, resources, properties-file

I would like to get access to files in resources folder my web app (independently from this is exploaded WAR or not). I have already used servletContext via Spring to getResource also FileSystem context.

In the end, I choose Spring ResourceLoader because seems that it's the most suitable approach in my case.

I don't like use @PropertySources annotation and get access to particular properties  of *.properties files.

**UPDATED**
I deployed my app using Webspehere Liberty Profile.

```
@Component
public class FileCreator {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    public String getRealPath(String location) {

        String realPath = null;
        try {

            Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(location);
            String resourceDesc = resource.getDescription();
            realPath = resource.getURI().getPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return realPath;
    }
}
```

I have common maven layout for my Gradle app. It means that myApp.properties file located in /WEB-INF/classes folder

```
String scheduledServicesRealPath1 = fileCreator.getRealPath("classpath:myApp.properties");
```

I want to get the absolute path for this file but I 'm getting just null.

**Does it exist any approach which can access resources independently from Application server, way of presentation of app on server (exploaded or not) and independent from file system?**

Comment: The ServletContext for accessing resources of the webapp, out of the classpath, or the ClassLoader, for accessing resources in the classpath, are standard ways to access resources, and work everywhere, whether the war is exploded or not. What's the problem with them?

Comment: @JBNizet I've just updated my question. Please, can you revise my question? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a path? What's the point? Just load the resource using `ResourceLoader.getResource(location).getInputStream()`.

Comment: @JBNizet I would like to use NIO2 api. I use utility class for getting absolute path to file. And then use this value to read all lines from file. I don't need input stream at once.

Comment: The fact is: a resource is NOT a file. When the resource is in a jar file of an exploded app, it's a jar file entry. When the resource is a file of a non-exploded war, it's an entry of the war file. This sequence of bytes, accessible using getInputStream(), is not a file on the file system.